# how many ways to create PrintWriter object in jsp and servlets?

Tags: jsp, printwriter

How many ways to create `PrintWriter` object using JSP and servlets?
I am using JSP as well as servlets for better performance I am using:

```
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
```

How many ways to create write instead of this?

Comment: probably no reason to such optimisation

Comment: How many ways do you need? What's wrong with the one you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following types:

```
PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(out, true);
PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(System.out, true); // for console print
PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(response.getWriter(), true);
PrintWriter pout = response.getWriter();
```

Comment: Thanq this is i want to expect from my question chandu D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `out` PrintWriter object

```
out.println("...");
```

You can use `pageContext` to get JspWriter:

```
pageContext.getOut()
```

Or you can just print a value

```
<% String value ="...";%>
<%=value%>
```

Comment: Thanq but i want to use out for creating html

Comment: You can create e.g. out.println("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>");

Answer (score 0):

First Import Class :

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
```

You can use it in Jsp and Servlet as :

```
String output="Something";
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8"));
```

or you can simply output as :

```
out.println(output);
```